# Missing Barcode at Generate PDF Report on Odoo v10

Tags: python, pdf, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying generate Product Labels to PDF and it is generated but missing the product barcode.

But The same Qweb I generate the Product Labels to HTML and it work fine.

**Go to Products and select two:**

[image]

**Generated the Product Labels as HTML (Work Fine):**

[image]

**Generated the Product Labels as PDF (Missing Barcode):**

[image]

**This is my QWEB:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="product.report_productlabel">
<t t-call="report.html_container">
<div class="page">
  <style>

  </style>

  <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="template">
    <t t-foreach="template.product_variant_ids" t-as="product">

      <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding:0;">
        <table style="border-spacing:0;margin-bottom:0;height: 110px;border: 2px solid black;" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr style="width: 3in;">
              <td style="width: 2.63in;text-align: center;background-color: #fff;" colspan="2" class="col-xs-8 danger">
                <strong style="text-transform: uppercase;">
                  <t t-esc="product.name"/>
                </strong>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr style="width: 1in;">
              <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 0px solid #fff; padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;" class="col-xs-5">
                <h4 style="border: 4px solid #ff4040;border-radius: 9px;background-color: #ffff00;padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;font-size: 26px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
                  <strong t-field="product.list_price" />

                  <strong>
                    <t t-esc="product.company_id.currency_id.symbol"/>
                  </strong>
                </h4>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;border-top: 0px solid #fff;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;" class="col-xs-7">
                <img class="img-responsive"
                     t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % res_company.logo"
                     style="background-color: #fff;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: auto;height: 16px;margin-bottom: 8px;"/>
                <img class="img-responsive" t-if="product.barcode"
                     t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('EAN13', product.barcode, 650, 200)"
                     style="height: 20px;width: 100%;"/>
                <span style="">
                  <t t-esc="product.barcode"/>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </t>
  </t>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem when you are behind a proxy, in your case NGNIX. But I can fix it following steps:

**First Solution:**

1- Add the following line inside odoo/addons/report/models/report.py file line number 205:

```
#base_url = irconfig_obj.get_param('report.url') or irconfig_obj.get_param('web.base.url')
base_url = irconfig_obj.get_param('web.base.url.report')
```

2- Add the server parameter web.base.url.report with value "http://127.0.0.1:8069" (Running Port).

> (With the Debug Actived) Go to Settings -> Parameters ->  System
>   Parameters -> Create

3- Restart the Odoo Server and It will work.

```
/etc/init.d/odoo restart
```

**UPDATE thanks to @CZoellner:**

The `@CZoellner` recommendation work too and don't change anything in code:

**Second Solution (RECOMMENDED):**

1- Add or UPDATE the server parameter url.report with value "http://127.0.0.1:8069" (Running Port).

> (With the Debug Actived) Go to Settings -> Parameters ->  System
>   Parameters -> Create

2- Restart the Odoo Server and It will work.

```
/etc/init.d/odoo restart
```

Reference: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/1105

Comment: Adding the parameter `report.url` isn't enough? I've set up some Odoo instances with nginx without a problem adding this parameter. No code changes necessary.

Comment: Do you have nginx with ssl (https)? My problems was only to generate Product Labels. I try only change the `report.url`. Thanks @CZoellner for your response.